# How to edit a JSON files non string values using powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have an appsettings.json file that looks like this

```
{
"ApiSettings": {
    "EnableSwagger": true,
    "UrlListeners": [
        "http://localhost:9000"
    ],
    "DebugMode":  true
},
}
```

And I am wanting to write some powershell that changes the "UrlListeners" portion. So far I've got

```
$DebugValue = 'false'
$JsonFile = Get-Content .\appsettings.json -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$JsonFile.ApiSettings.DebugMode = $DebugValue
$JsonFile | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9| Set-Content .\appsettings.json
```

However instead of just outputting
`"DebugMode": false`
I get
`"DebugMode": "false"`

How do I set the value with it having quotes? Thanks in advance

Comment: `$DebugValue = $false`. In other words, you need a regular Boolean value here, not a string

Comment: Isn't it easy when you know how! Thanks for the help, seems so obvious now!!